# Discord.py | When working with embeds, how does one use a for loop to generate a variable's worth of fields?

Tags: python, for-loop, discord.py, embed

I'm currently working on a discord.py dice roller command that allows one to input an argument for a number of dice to roll. As this command outputs to an embed, I would like each dice roll to output to it's own embed field using a for loop that executes the same number of times as the variable that contains the argument's amount of dice.

I've attempted quite a few types of for loops, but I think I'm doing something fundamentally wrong. Unfortunately, Discord.py is not returning any errors when I run this for loop so I can't even begin to wrap my head around why...

```
diceNum = 5
diceRange = range(diceNum)

for dice in diceRange:
    print(f'test: {dice}')
    embed.add_field(name=f"{dice}",
                    value=f"{diceName} is a(n)...\n {diceResult}**!",
                    inline=True)
```

My assumption is that one cannot add an embed field without doing some special method of sorts, and as stated previously when I run this code it simply outputs nothing. No error, and cuts the command short too. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, SO!

Edit: Here's the embed assignment!

```
embed = discord.Embed(
    title="Test Dice Roller",
    description=f"You've rolled {diceNum} {diceName} dice, Good luck!\n\n",
    color=diceColor,
)
```

Comment: You can do it like this, could you show your embed assignment ? `embed = ??`

Comment: Sure! (the formatting looks awful so I'll edit it into the post as well)

`embed = discord.Embed(

            title="Test Dice Roller",

            description=f"You've rolled {diceNum} {diceName} dice, Good luck!\n\n",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is correct, check the `color`

here is my little test with a change in the for loop statement

```py
@bot.command()
async def dice(ctx):

    diceNum = 5
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title="Test Dice Roller",
        description=f"You've rolled {diceNum}",
    )

    for dice in range(diceNum):
        embed.add_field(name=dice, value='something')

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

[image]

Comment: Fascinating, thank you very much Abdulaziz! Do you have any idea on why the color was causing this to not work?

Comment: the color should be like this `color=discord.Colour.red()` [for more colors](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=color#discord.Colour)